# How to calculate Binary histogram of an image?

Tags: image-processing, histogram, feature-detection, image-segmentation

suppose a color image of size 256x256, how can I calculate the bianry histogram of the image? also which is the data structure suited to store the histogram if I want to cluster similar images?
 Please note that the histogram must be saved in the database along with the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Matlab:
rgb2gray and imhist can help you. If you need only 2 values try converting it to binary image

Comment: I'm using java.. I am making a content-based Image Retrieval system.. and I am using Binary histogram as the feature extraction algorithm.